How to mount a Vue or React app in shadow dom without using iframe?
I have a small chat app that I want to be like a chatbot on any other website but I do not want to use iframe for it. I checked dialogflow messenger and it does not seem to be using iframe but uses shadow dom to render the messenger.
class ChatWidgetSDK extends HTMLElement {
  static observedAttributes = ["height", "width"];
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

    // Default settings
    this.settings = {
      buttonColor: "#007bff",
      buttonText: "",
      chatUrl: "http://localhost:8080",
      width: "300px",
      height: "400px",
      position: { bottom: "20px", right: "20px" },
    };

    // Create chat button
    this.chatButton = document.createElement("button");
    this.chatButton.id = "chat-button";
    this.chatButton.innerHTML = this.settings.buttonText;

    // Create chat modal
    this.chatModal = document.createElement("div");
    this.chatModal.id = "chat-modal";
    this.chatModal.innerHTML = `
      <iframe
        id="chat-iframe"
        src="${this.settings.chatUrl}"
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;"
      ></iframe>
    `;
    this.chatModal.style.display = "none"; // Initially hidden

    // Apply styles
    this.applyStyles();

    // Attach elements
    shadow.appendChild(this.chatButton);
    shadow.appendChild(this.chatModal);

    // Attach event listeners
    this.attachEventListeners();
  }

  applyStyles() {
    const style = document.createElement("style");
    style.textContent = `
      #chat-button {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: ${this.settings.position.bottom};
        right: ${this.settings.position.right};
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: ${this.settings.buttonColor};
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 24px;
        z-index: 1000;
      }
      #chat-modal {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: calc(${this.settings.position.bottom} + 70px);
        right: ${this.settings.position.right};
        width: ${this.settings.width};
        height: ${this.settings.height};
        border: none;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1000;
        background: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    `;
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
  }

  // For open and close of the chat modal
  attachEventListeners() {
    this.chatButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (this.chatModal.style.display === "none") {
        this.chatModal.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        this.chatModal.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  }

  openChat() {
    this.chatModal.style.display = "block";
  }

  closeChat() {
    this.chatModal.style.display = "none";
  }

  // Is used to add custom settings to the given param
  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (oldValue !== newValue) {
      this.settings[name] = newValue;
      this.applyStyles();
    }
  }
}

// Define the custom element
customElements.define("chat-widget-sdk", ChatWidgetSDK);

this is what am doing currently but it uses iframe to render the app but I would like to do it without the iframe, so is there a way to do this?. Any suggestions or solutions that I can use to do this?
